# .[NSOpenPanel directoryURL] gives error: No visible @interface for 'NSOpenPanel' declares the selector 'directoryURL:'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm using Xcode, building with base SDK and deployment target: `OS X 10.8`, trying to use `[NSOpenPanel directoryURL]` which the [offical documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSSavePanel/directoryURL) says is

> Available in OS X v10.6 and later

But I get the error:

> ARC Semantic issue - No visible @interface for 'NSOpenPanel' declares the selector 'directoryURL:'

Code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
// #import <NSOpenPanel.h> // No good
@import AppKit;

void fileOpen()
{
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    // [openPanel setDirectory:@""]; // works, but deprecated in OSX 10.6
    [openPanel directoryURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///path/"]];
    // ...
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directoryURL` is a property and does not take a string argument like what you were originally guessing.  That's why you were seeing the error when trying to resolve the `directoryURL:'` selector.

The `directoryURL` property does have a getter and setter, though.

Try using:

```
[openPanel setDirectoryURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///path/"]];
```

or:

```
openPanel.directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"path"];
```

Comment: oops you're right, it's a property. All this language switching is confusing my brain. Thanks.